# Error establishing a database connection - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

How am I going to fix this problem? I tried many methods to solve this one but none of them work.I already changed the default value on each forms,still the same. Need some advice here. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k3vS.png)

Comment: Did you checked the db credentials given? if not working try with mysql connect and check whether connection is working properly or not.

Comment: Not yet.. How? BTW, not too long since I studied this one.

Comment: wp-config.php file did you given the exact the db credentials? else check the credentials is working or not. Here is link for how to check db connection is working or not. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Should I delete the wp-config-sample.php and change it to wp-config.php instead?

Comment: no dont delete it instead create a copy of wp-config-sample.php and rename to wp-config.php and give the credentials in wp-config.php file.... Please mention in the question that seems you haven't added the wp-config.php correctly

Comment: are u working on localhost or any web server there are mainly three parameters u need to match on wp-config.php first is database name and second username and password..

Answer (score 0):

try this->

```
$con=new MySQLi("localhost","root","pwd","db");
try
{
if($con)
{
  echo "Db connected successfully"
}
else
{
  die("Error In Establishing Db Connection");
}
}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

then after include this connection file in other where u need it use $con object to fire queries and get results.Also Check your wp.config file for credentials and database and also for localhost

Comment: Mind you guys that I was still in installation phase.

Comment: If Wp-config.php doesnot exist then you have given code for that during wordpress installtion create wp-config file by pasting that code then open wp-config-sample.php  in which u write credential from wp-config.php file u have created  then rename wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php and delete old wp-config file then in browser go to localhost/wpfolder/ if everything is write you can access it